# How to mimic java's wildcard in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a situation like the following:

```
public class BasicContainer {
}

public class SpecificContainerA : BasicContainer {
}

public class SpecificContainerB : BasicContainer {
}

public class BuilderA<T> where T : BasicContainer 
{
    public bool IsPrimary { ... }
}

public class BuilderB : BuilderA<SpecificContainer>
{
    public bool IsHidden { ... }

}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar Foo(string id, Action<BuilderB> action) {

    }
}
```

In other words I have a class which inherit of another parametrized class and fixes this type parameter. In one of my other class I have a method which take an action on this class.

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
public Action<BuilderA<T>> Bla<T>()
    where T : BasicContainer
{
    return c => c.IsPrimary();
}

bar.Foo("id", Bla<SpecificContainerB>());
```

Meaning, I want to give to my method `Foo` a more generic action over T as a parameter.

PS: I figured out I could do something like:

```
 public class Bar
 {
    public Bar Foo<T1, T2>(string id, T1 action)
        where T1 : Action<T2>
        where T2 : Container
    {

    }
 }
```

But this is truly ugly and I expect something nicer. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think I deleted a comment... I didn't want to!

Comment: I deleted my comment after reading your question more closely.

Comment: There's no reason to "mimic" anything from java in C#. C# is a clearly superior language with real generics (as opposed to java's fake generics that get erased) and doesn't need any of the horrible hacks you need in java for anything.

Comment: Your design is extremely convoluted, and the code sample you have posted does not compile, and does not make sense. Please clarify. My above comment still stands.

Comment: Ok I'll clarify but later, I have to leave now.

Answer (score 0):

`Action<T>` is sealed so you can't derive from it anyways. Your class is the equivalent of:

```
 public class Bar
 {
    public Bar Foo<T>(string id, Action<T> action)
        where T : Container
    {

    }
 }
```

or, based on your original example:

```
 public class Bar
 {
    public Bar Foo<T1, T2>(string id, Action<T1> action)
        where T1 : BuilderA<T2>
        where T2 : Container
    {

    }
 }
```

And since the compiler can infer the type of `T` from the action passed in you shouldn't need to specify the generic parameters.